# Magento 2 After plugin with parameter

Tags: magento2, di.xml

I am trying to implement after plugin to the following method.

```
public function getCategoryUrl($category)
{
    if ($category instanceof ModelCategory) {
        return $category->getUrl();
    }
    return $this->_categoryFactory->create()->setData($category->getData())->getUrl();
}
```

Please note the `$category` parameter passed to the above method.

As the resolution, I have implemented below code.

```
public function afterGetCategoryUrl(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $subject, $result)
{
    return $result;
}
```

Now, my question is: How do I get the `$category` parameter passed in parent method to my plugin? I just want to modify result based on the certain value in `$category` object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need input parameters and you also need to change output, you can use an **around** plugin or an **after** plugin:

Example using `around`:

```
public function aroundGetCategoryUrl(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    $category
) {
   $originalResult = $proceed($category);
   
   if (...) {
      ...
      return $otherResult;
   }

   return $originalResult;
}
```

Example using `after`:

```
public function afterGetCategoryUrl(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $subject,
    $result,
    $category
) {
   if (...) {
      ...
      return $otherResult;
   }

   return $result;
}
```

**Just a note:**

Please notice that if you are going to change an internal behaviour, a **preference** could be a better option that a **plugin**. It depends on what you are going to do.

Comment: I just want to modify the result.

Comment: See my updated post.

Comment: Yes that (AroundPlugin) Works but it would be great if we can achieve this using (AfterPlugin).

Comment: There is no way with "after" plugins since it is not intended to work this way, what you need can only be done with "around" plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. i am fine with "around" as well

Comment: Can we please confirm. Is the around method still the best thing to use in this questions exact situation? I'm just trying to modify a result, (a preference seems like overkill) in my case I'm working with $product->getMetaDescription(). It was suggest below that we can use parameters in the after method (as of version 2.2) but it's not working for me.  "around" might just be best? Was looking to confirm please. Thank you!

Comment: @Phoenix128_RiccardoT, I have similar question, can u help me to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273030/get-product-info-from-afteraddproduct-plugin-in-magento-2

Answer (score 15):

Since Magento 2.2 it is possible to have input parameters in after plugin

```
namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class AuthLogger
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth $authModel
     * @param null $result
     * @param string $username
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterLogin(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth $authModel, $result, $username)
    {
        $this->logger->debug('User ' . $username . ' signed in.');
    }
}
```

See Magento documentation for details  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#after-methods

Answer (score 0):

> **Try below after and around plugins**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Msquare
  @author      Mahesh Makwana
  -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category">
        <plugin name="plugin_with_params"
                type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\CategoryPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> **Around Plugin**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin**

**CategoryPlugin.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * Msquare
 * @author      Mahesh Makwana
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CategoryPlugin
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundGetCategoryUrl(Category $subject, callable $proceed, $category)
    {
        $result = $proceed($category);
        // return $result;
        
        //$this->logger->debug('Plugin  called');
        ...................................
        ..... Add Your Logic Here .........
        ...................................

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> **After Plugin**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin**

**CategoryPlugin.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * Msquare
 * @author      Mahesh Makwana
 */
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CategoryPlugin
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function afterGetCategoryUrl(Category $subject, $result, $category)
    {
        // return $result;  -> Original Result

        //$this->logger->debug('Plugin  called');
        ...................................
        ..... Add Your Logic Here .........
        ...................................

        return $result;
    }
}
```

***Note: Please be aware that when considering changes to internal behavior in class, using a preference might be a more suitable option than a plugin. The choice between preference and plugin depends on the specific task or modification you intend to make within the class.***