# Is it possible to change output function call parameters using a plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

Like I have this function

```
public function letsTry(){
 $this->callFuncion($name1, $name2, true);
}

private function callFunction($arg1, $arg2, $arg3 = false){
  // do stuff
}
```

How i can change the 3rd parameter `true` to `false` using plugin or remove it. Or i need to use preference for this?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible we can change output value or any other param value using plugin but make sure you are using plugin on public function because plugin only work on public class not on end classes. if you want to change param value before executing function then you can use **"Before Plugin"** if you want to change param value or output value then you should you **"After plugin"** and if you want to do modification during function execution then you can use **"Around plugin"**.

you can use blow links as reference for how plugin works:

[Magento 2 After plugin with parameter](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171187/magento-2-after-plugin-with-parameter)
[How plugin work](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

If you find this answer useful then upvote this answers. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

You can use before plugin

```
public function beforecallFunction(\Vendor\Module\Your\Class$subject, $arg1, $arg2, $arg3)
    {
        return [ $arg1,$arg2,false];
    }
```

Update: You cannot apply plugins to Non-public methods 
so this will not work

Comment: Thats private function bro.

Comment: sorry didn`t mentioned that it privatte